# How to provide edit option for custom post type in admin section

Tags: wordpress

I created custom post type "testimonials", which are being displayed with 5 columns follow title, client, thumbnail, category, and date in admin section under testimonials tab, resembles users lists in admin section. Now i want to give edit option for first column ie "Title" in the list. When admin clicks on the "Title" then user must be redirected to edit page for editing facility. Should i place filter hook for changing first column "Title" with link. Thank You in advance.

1. Title(Need Edit option like users list in wordpress admin section)
2. client
3. thumbnail
4. category
5. date

Answer (score 0):

By default wordpress comes with an edit link on every page. If a user is permitted to edit a post, then an edit link will be shown to them. You can just change the position of this link and bring it under title. If your theme doesn't have this option you can add it

```
<?php edit_post_link(); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you.. omer Farooq.. I clearly understood your point. It is great pleasure to have your response. I will try and let you know the status soon